# Using dynamic objects in codedom created LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, codedom, expandoobject

I tried to use expandoobjects in LINQ queries to have the ability to query against properties that are created during runtime, for example the headers from a csv file. It all worked fine if typing the LINQ query direct in the code as in the example:

```
// initialize testdata
List<ExpandoObject> hans = new List<ExpandoObject>();
string[] names = {"Apfel", "Birne", "Banane", "Orange"};
int[] ids = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   dynamic horst = new ExpandoObject();
   ((IDictionary<string, object>)horst).Add("Fruit", names[i]);
   ((IDictionary<string, object>)horst).Add("ID", ids[i]);
   hans.Add(horst);
}

// try some LINQ queries, both are working as intended
var klaus = from dynamic x in hans where x.ID < 3 select x;
//var klaus = hans.Where(x => x.ID < 3).Select(x => x);
```

Then i tried to read the query from the commandline and create a dynamic LINQ query using a slighty modified version of the evaluant linq compiler.

```
string expression = System.Console.ReadLine();
LinqCompiler lc = new LinqCompiler(expression);
lc.AddSource<ExpandoObject>("hans", hans);
IEnumerable<ExpandoObject> klaus = (IEnumerable<ExpandoObject>)lc.Evaluate();
```

As long as as i don´t use WHERE or ORDER BY statements, everything is fine, but if any WHERE or ORDER BY is included in the query, i get an error when compiling the codedom code in the linq compiler: *CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation.*

The code for the query is created using the following line:

```
doRequestMethod.Statements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeSnippetExpression(Query)));
```

I suppose that the codedom compiler is building the expression tree in some way different to the way a direct typed in LINQ query is parsed. Any idea to get this to work would be appretiated, including other ideas to dynamically create queries for runtime-generated objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the error you're getting, I had to fix the [LINQ Compiler](http://linqcompiler.codeplex.com/) to support `dynamic`, by telling it to use C# 4.0 and add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll, so I assume you have done the same.

The problem is a source in LINQ compiler can be any collection, including `IQueryable<T>`. And if `IQueryable<T>` is supposed to work correctly, you actually need to treat it as `IQueryable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. The way LINQ compiler solves this is that it treats *any* source as `IQuerybale<T>`by using the `AsQueryable()` extension method.

This means the generated code looks like this:

```
public object DoRequest(System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject> hans) {
    return from dynamic x in hans where x.ID < 3 select x;
}
```

The problem with this code is that tries to use `IQuerybale<T>` versions of LINQ methods, that use `Expression`s. And, as the error message tells you, `Expression`s don't support `dynamic`.

I think the easiest way to fix this is to modify LINQ Compiler to use `IEnumerable<T>`, instead of `IQuerybale<T>` by changing the `AddSource()` into:

```
public void AddSource<T>(string name, IEnumerable<T> source) 
{
    this.sources.Add(new SourceDescription(name, typeof(IEnumerable<T>), source));
}
```

Of course, this means it won't work well for database queries, but you can't make database queries work with `dynamic` anyway.

Comment: Thank you, this made it work if changing the call of the DoRequest method, too. It is based on a List<IQueryable> list and calls toQueryabale() on your source.  

     `List<IEnumerable> list = new List<IEnumerable>();  

    foreach (SourceDescription source in this.sources)  
    {  
         list.Add(source.Instance);  
    }`